# Hosting REST webservice on WCF with IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, iis

Here's my simplified example:

web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Services.DBService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/" binding="webHttpBinding"
          contract="Contracts.IDBService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Supported by the following contract:

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IDBService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        Services.Person GetData(string id);
    }

}
```

and service:

```
using System.ServiceModel.Web;

namespace Services
{
    public class DBService : Contracts.IDBService
    {
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "data/{id}")]
        public Person GetData(string id)
        {
            return new Person()
            {
                Id = int.Parse(id),
                Name = "John Doe"
            };
        }
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Running via IIS Express in the debugger, I can make a GET request to localhost/data/10.

When I try and publish this locally to IIS, however, I get a 404 error when I try to go to localhost/data/10. I'm putting this in the default web application with a root of localhost.

Is there something I need to be aware of using `UriTemplate` that I don't know about? What am I doing incorrectly?

It's part of an app pool running .NET 4.0, and this app pool is started. Error code:

```
Module IIS Web Core 
Notification MapRequestHandler 
Handler StaticFile 
Error Code 0x80070002 
Requested URL http://localhost:80/Data/10 
Physical Path C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Data\10 
Logon Method Anonymous 
Logon User Anonymous
```

It's trying to find the physical location, and obviously it doesn't exist. How can I configure it to not do this?

Not sure what other info to give, but ask and you will receive...

Comment: This isn't terribly helpful, but for REST, WCF is out and MVC/WebAPI is in.

Comment: WebInvoke attribute supposed to be used with POST request. For GET you should use WebGet attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking EVERYWHERE for an answer that actually would work, I found something [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basically, you need to mark the services with `AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute` like so to enable AspNet compatibility:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class DBService : Contracts.IDBService
```

and then add a tag to the Web.Config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Enabling Aspnet compatibility is an old trick and you shouldn't fall for it unless your REST API is targeted to work with only .Net ecosystem clients.

Comment: @vendettamit, what's the alternative?

Comment: My bad!!! In Configuration it would be required because Routing is one of feature that comes from Asp.net. But marking methods with AspNetCompatibilityRequirements shouldn't be required unless you're going to them in Asp.net Ajax services.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some configuration setting in Web.config to define the Route information. So that IIS understand where to redirect the incoming request.

Add following in your web.config:

```
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule"
         type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  </modules>
  <handlers>
    <add name="UrlRoutingHandler"
       preCondition="integratedMode"
       verb="*" path="UrlRouting.axd"
       type="System.Web.HttpForbiddenHandler, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
  </handlers>
```

Add reference to `System.ServiceModel.Activation` library and add `Global.asax` file in your WCF library project and add below code in `Application_Start` method.

```
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("", new WebServiceHostFactory(), typeof(<your service>)));
    }
```

Publish again and you should be good to go.

You can also check out this [project](https://github.com/vendettamit/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions) for [sample](https://github.com/vendettamit/WebHttpBehaviorExtensions/tree/master/src/WcfWebHttpIISHostingSample) of hosting `WCF` `REST` service in IIS. Also the library provides custom behavior to support Typed argument in methods which are marked with URI Template.

Comment: What is this doing? also it looks like the application_start is an event handler. Where is it registered? Since it works in the debugger host (IIS Express) but not on IIS... what's different between the two? If it works on one why do I need to add extra configuration to the other?

Comment: If you read the answer everything is explained which part belong to where. It works in debugger cause both are diff servers. Development server is not fully functional as IIS. And dev server works with VS. when the app is on IIS it works based on the components specified in configuration.